# How to find a specific value within vector of objects

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of class Weapon which then loops through and adding the id values to the vector.

```
Weapon* weapon;
vector<Weapon*> weaponVector;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    weapon = new Weapon(i);
    weaponVector.push_back(weapon);
}
```

I then have a vector iterator to try and find the specified number within the vector.

```
vector<Weapon*>::iterator findIt;
findIt = find(weaponVector.begin(), weaponVector.end(), 5);
```

In the Weapon class I have created an operator overload to check if the id's are the same.

```
bool Weapon::operator==(const Weapon& rhs)
{
    return (rhs.id == id);
}
```

**Quesion:**

I am trying to find the number 5 within the weaponVector, however I keep getting this error:

```
C2446 '==': no conversion from 'const int' to 'Weapon *
```

**Things I have tried:**

```
findIt = find(weaponVector.begin(), weaponVector.end(), Weapon(5));

Weapon five = Weapon(5);
findIt = find(weaponVector.begin(), weaponVector.end(), five);
```

I keep getting errors regardless what I try. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you dynamically allocating `Weapon` objects?  If you want to play with dynamic allocation, you should have a `std::vector` of smart pointers.  Otherwise, create a temporary weapon, initialize it, then `push_back` into the vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use copies of weapons in your vector rather than pointers:

```
std::vector<Weapon> weaponVector;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Weapon w = Weapon(i); // Create a temporary weapon.
    weaponVector.push_back(weapon);  // Copy the temporary and place into the vector.
}
```

By using copies, you eliminate the hassles of dynamic memory management and also having to dereference pointers.

Your search loop:

```
vector<Weapon>::iterator findIt;
Weapon w5 = Weapon(5);
findIt = find(weaponVector.begin(), weaponVector.end(), w5);
```

Note that I created a temporary because you don't have an `operator==(unsigned int)` defined in your class (or you haven't shown it).  The `find` function wants the search value to be of the same type as the objects in the vector.

Comment: This is what I was after, thanks. I used the pointers because at the time it wouldn't let me pushback the Weapon instance and I didn't think to make a temporary Weapon!

Answer (score 2):

If using C++11, simply use `std::find_if` with a lambda function:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
int number_to_find = 5;
auto findIt = std::find_if(weaponVector.begin(), weaponVector.end(), 
                          [&](Weapon* ptr) { return ptr->id == number_to_find;});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `std::find_if` function. You can then pass a function which can do the comparison between a `Weapon` and the id number. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find.

Answer (score 0):

Your Vector holds pointers to Weapon (`Weapon*`) while your find is searching for the integer 5 (a `const int`). Comparing both doesnt make sense, since you dont want to know if any of the Weapon-Objects is stored at memory-address "5".

Comparing a `Weapon*` to an actual `Weapon` doesnt make much sense either, since an object and its memory adress are not the same.

So either you use `std::find_if` or you use a `std::vector<Weapon>` and store Weapon-Objects directly.